# How to redirect url with incorrect parameter to index page?

Tags: php, .htaccess

Following url works fine and displays an image :

```
http://example.com/?pic=blob&pic_blobid=8569a
```

At the same time on passing incorrect parameters in the same url as below , shows an empty page .

```
http://example.com/?pic=blob&pic_blobid=8569@  /* blobid here is incorrect */
```

I have htaccess rule for 404 pages as :

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://example.com
```

but error link (i.e `http://example/?pic=blob&pic_blobid=8569@` ) is not taken either as error one

My question is :

> Is there any way to redirect links with incorrect parameters (like :
>   `http://example.com/?pic=blob&pic_blobid=8569@` to
>   `http://example.com` ) to another link   ?

*Thanks for having a look into question.*

**Edit 1 :**

`Blod_id` (parameters can be any value say `int` , `char` ) , as mentioned by @rupal in comments it should be verified from dataset values , but the project has too many instances of the same , is there any possibility to filter them from `htaccess` ?

Comment: `if( isset($_GET['pic_blobid']) && !is_number($_GET['pic_blobid']) ){ header("HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently"); header("Location: http://example.com"); exit; }`

Comment: @SimoneNigro , id can be other than int also , have edited the link in question to include char with id

Comment: If its coming from DB then instead of using is_number, you can check that dataset is empty with that id filter from database query. OR if its fix set of checking then you may create an array and can check in it

Comment: @utility your question is very vague...

Comment: @Rupal yes .. but project have several instances of the same..was thinking was there any htaccess rule to accomplish the same rather changing the code of entire project

Comment: @SimoneNigro actually project is missing validation as mentioned in one of the comments (check dataset) , i was thinking whether there would be any fix from htaccess level

Comment: No, it won't be possible to check at htaccess level. You'll need to validate the params in your PHP script.

Comment: thank you @hjpotter92 for your thoughts..

Comment: htaccess cannot check values against your database. You will need to run query inside php code and then return 404 if needed

Comment: thank you @anubhava , now im sure it wont be possible from ur comments :)